# Android Deleted File Search

Tags: android, mobile, memory-management

I am starting with android development. And based on the use case i want to create the app for recovering the deleted files.

Deleted as in deleted from Recycle bin itself. Can anybody guide me through how I scan the memory to identify what memory structure are full vs empty. I know that when the file is deleted it is still in memory. Android just forgot its location. I want to find and then recompile the file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First: there is no Recycle bin. Second: files are stored in storage. Not in memory. Third: this looks an appropriate  starting point for Android development ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to go that path please consider my advice instead.

Since you are new to android and just starting android development. Consider picking up a simpler project so you can understand the basics first. Tring to get memory access and recover lost files requires a lot of understand of the android architecture, and most of apps, even after being granted admin permissions i.e getting root access (in a rooted device) are not able to recover deleted files.

Here are some ideas to help you get started

Consider [a toDo app](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj69bKPuK34AhXKh1wKHX99B5oQFnoECBEQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sitepoint.com%2Fstarting-android-development-creating-todo-app%2F&usg=AOvVaw38onhvhXZyD7n0nT4EeRu6), or a [weather app](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi90e27ua34AhUSiVwKHaFBChgQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geeksforgeeks.org%2Fhow-to-build-a-weather-app-in-android%2F&usg=AOvVaw0gwE-2kdoSRy-l8gqkd15O)